# generate all permutations with repetition....non-recursive in C

Tags: c, permutation, non-recursive

So I would like to know how to write a non-recursive function to print all permutations given an N and r where `r^N` gives you the total number of permutations.

```
Example: N = 3, r = 2, total permutations = 8

output:
000
001
010
011
100
101
110
111
```

This is what I tried but of course it only works for one case:

```
void perm_iter(int N, int nr_vals){

    int pos = N-1;
    int i,j,k;
    int P_array[N];
    for(i=0;i<N;i++){
        P_array[i] = 0;
    }
    int val_array[nr_vals];
    for(i=0;i<nr_vals;i++){
        val_array[i] = i;
    }

    do{
        for(i=0;i<N;i++){
            for(j=0;j<nr_vals;j++){
                P_array[pos-1] = val_array[j];
                for(k=0;k<nr_vals;k++){
                    P_array[pos] = val_array[k];
                    for(i=0;i<N;i++){
                        printf("%d",P_array[i]);
                    }
                    printf("\n");
                }
            }
            pos--;
        }
    }while(pos > 0);
}
```

Comment: It's easy one use queue.

Comment: never used one before. I'll look into it. Thanks

Comment: I believe google does not show up on your side of the world. Anyways, check out- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/138934/Non-recursive-Permutations-and-Combinations and http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/885226-all-permutations-non-recursive

Comment: The first article is a little rough for me to follow because I'm just now learning Java. I can follow the second one but I can't use Modulus and i'm trying not to use strings. Thanks for the help though

Comment: All you need to do is count. `r` is the base, `N` is the number of digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an odometer function with variable radix, not really a permutation.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void show(int *a, int n)
{
int i;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%1d", a[i]);
    printf("\n");
}

void gen_all_numbers(int r, int n)
{
int i;
int *a;
    if(r < 2 || n < 1)          /* parameter check */
        return;
    r -= 1;                     /* r = max digit value */
    a = malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)      /* start with all zeroes */
        a[i] = 0;
    show(a, n);
    while(1){
        i = n - 1;
        while(a[i] < r){        /* increment last digit */
            a[i]++;
            show(a,n);
        }
        /* find next digit to increment */
        while(i >= 0 && a[i] == r)
            i--;
        if(i < 0)break;         /* return if done */
        a[i]++;
        while(++i < n)          /* zero following digits */
            a[i] = 0;
        show(a,n);
    }
    free(a);
}

int main()
{
    gen_all_numbers(2,4);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It works for me for the most part but for some reason it doesn't like it if you input an N value of 4..It seems like it gets stuck on second while loop,while(a[i] < r) , for some reason because it gets thrown in an infinite loop of 0001

Comment: figured it out...it just didn't like your malloc I changed it to a = malloc(sizeof(int)*(N+1)); and it works perfectly. Thanks again

Comment: @JoelMelendez - I updated my answer. The part after /* find next digit to increment */ was testing a[-1] == r, which could have caused access problem. The while loop now decrements i after testing for a[i] == r. I don't know why you had a problem with N = 4, since that is what I tested with. I also added a parameter check to make sure r >= 2, and n >= 1.

Answer (score 0):

This works. Just make sure you use the `-lm` option when compiling or you'll get an error about the `pow` function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

void perm(double r,double N){
  double num=pow(r,N);
  int count=(int)num;
  int n=0,b=0;
  for (n=0;n<count;n++){
    printf("%d: ",n);
    for (b=2;b>=0;b--){ //go through bits 2 to 0.
      if (n & (1<<b)){printf("1");}else{printf("0");}
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}

int main(){
  perm(2,3);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't even think of using bits. That's awesome.